# Odoo - always redirecting to "Create New Database" Page

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I moved all the files and database to another server. While running the application i was always redirecting to

> ":8069/web/database/manager#action=database_manager" 
>   this page.

Is there any idea, how should i get out from this?

Even if the new database is created, again it is redirecting to the same page..

Comment: owner of the database is same as old server?

Comment: yes, it is same in both the server